# Web-scraping multiple pages

Tags: r, rvest, purrr

I am trying to create a list of projects available through a website. However,I can't figure out why the following code doesn't seem to work.
In the first step, I create a loop to go through the pages and in the second step I use "selectorGadget" to find the Html element and save the table title in a dataframe.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

url_base<- "http://www.fao.org/forestry/vrd/data/by/funders#arrangements/q//t/2006-2028/f/585/r/all/a/0-1104/p/%d"


#function to loop through multiple pages
map_df(1:4, function(i){
page <- read_html(sprintf(url_base, i))
data.frame(Title = html_text(html_nodes(page, "h5")))
}) -> reddprojects
```

I want to extract the list of all the projects and the timeline. eg. The code on this webpage: 
          http://www.fao.org/forestry/vrd/data/by/funders#arrangements/q//t/2006-2028/f/585/r/all/a/0-1104/p/1
 should return the list of all the projects in the following format. For example, the first row should look like:

```
Title                                                     Period

A regional focus on sustainable.....                     2010 - 2010
```

Comment: I think the problem is coming at the step where you try to extract the text. (This is after correcting the package name to `purrr` and the function in the last line of your code to `html_text`.) When I tried it for one page, I got the right html back, but I get a null set with `html_nodes(page, "h5")`. If you fix that issue, I think this will work.

Comment: It is likely the page is created with javascript.  If you use the developer tools, it looks like this link: http://www.fao.org/forestry/vrd/data/by/funders/find-arrangements?q=&funderId=all&recipientId=all&startYear=2006&endYear=2028&minAmount=0&maxAmount=1104&page=1 has the information you are interested in.